# what can be best approch - Get all possible sublists

Tags: scala

I have a `List` `"a, b, c,d"`, and this is the expected result

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
b
bc
bcd
c
cd
d
```

I tried bruteforce, but I think, there might be any other efficient solution, provided I am having very long list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best solution but one way of doing this is by using `sliding` function as follow,

```
val lst = List('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

val groupedElements = (1 to lst.size).flatMap(x =>
      lst.sliding(x, 1))

groupedElements.foreach(x => println(x.mkString(""))) 

//output
  /*  a
      b
      c
      d
      ab
      bc
      cd
      abc
      bcd
      abcd
      */
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner.

```
"abcd".tails.flatMap(_.inits.toSeq.init.reverse).mkString(",")
//res0: String = a,ab,abc,abcd,b,bc,bcd,c,cd,d
```

The `mkString()` is added just so we can see the result. Otherwise the result is an `Iterator[String]`, which is a pretty memory efficient collection type.

The `reverse` is only there so that it comes out in the order you specified. If the order of the results is unimportant then that can be removed.

The `toSeq.init` is there to remove empty elements left behind by the `inits` call. If those can be dealt with elsewhere then this can also be removed.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution, but I think is a good one, and it's `tailrec`

First this function to get the possible sublists of a `List`

```
 def getSubList[A](lista: Seq[A]): Seq[Seq[A]] = {
      for {
        i <- 1 to lista.length
      } yield lista.take(i)
  }
```

And then this one to perform the recursion calling the first function and obtain all the sublists possible:

```
def getSubListRecursive[A](lista: Seq[A]): Seq[Seq[A]] = {
    @tailrec
    def go(acc: Seq[Seq[A]], rest: Seq[A]): Seq[Seq[A]] = {
      rest match {
        case Nil => acc
        case l => go(acc = acc ++ getSubList(l), rest= l.tail)
      }
    }
    go(Nil, lista)
  }
```

The ouput:

```
getSubListRecursive(l)


res4: Seq[Seq[String]] = List(List(a), List(a, b), List(a, b, c), List(a, b, c, d), List(b), List(b, c), List(b, c, d), List(c), List(c, d), List(d))
```